# Got NotSerializableException when putting Guava MultiTreemap in http session

Tags: java, spring-mvc, serialization, model-view-controller, guava

I wanted to put an instance of Guava TreeMultimap into the http session but I kept getting this exception: NotSerializableException

Anyone knows how to get around this?

My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{

        public void doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        {

                TreeMultimap<String, MyCustomClass> myMap = TreeMultimap.create(
                     new Comparator<String>()
                     {
                          @Override
                          public int compare(String o1, String o2)
                          {
                              return o1.compareTo(o2);
                          }
                     },
                     new Comparator<MyCustomClass>()
                     {
                           @Override
                           public int compare(MyCustomClass o1, MyCustomClass o2)
                           {
                               return o1.compareTo(o2);
                           }
                      });

                      request.getSession().setAttribute("MyAttribute", myMap); //==> ERROR HERE!

          }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that your `Comparator`s are not `Serializable`. Make each one a non-anonymous class that implements both `Comparator` and `Serializable` and you should be fine.

Actually, since both of your `Comparator`s are just implementing natural ordering, you should just be able to write

```
TreeMultimap<String, MyCustomClass> myMap = TreeMultimap.create();
```

Comment: hey Colin.
Just edited my question. The second generic type is a custom class, NOT `String`.

Comment: Yeah. I figured out the problem was because my `MyCustomClass` wasn't serializable. Made it implement `Serializable`, and everything works now. Thanks